# can i play my electric guitar on a midi sequencer?

Tags: guitar, midi, ableton-live

for example in ableton live , connect my guitar and program a melody, is that possible? I don't know if this could be done, it would be interesting to me instead of using virtual instruments.

Comment: There's a Sonuus G2M module that the guitar plugs into, then it goes into any MIDI module, then into an amp. But only single note playing is available at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to do it.

One popular standard is to use special separate pickups for each of the six strings, e.g. Roland GK-3 or RMC pickups, output signal via a 13-pin connector to a converter, e.g. Roland GR-55 or Axon AX 100 mkII, which produces polyphonic MIDI signal that can be connected to a computer. You need a MIDI audio interface to connect a MIDI cable to a computer; MIDI USB can be connected directly to a computer.

There are also solutions, both hardware and software, that allow to use regular guitar pickups. In most cases they are monophonic, i.e. they can recognize only one note at a time, they won't convert chords, but some products also support polyphonic signals. A software solution might be the cheapest one.

Finally there are instruments which resemble a guitar in looks and feel, but are in fact solely MIDI controllers. A notable example is SynthAxe.

On this site we don't recommend specific products, and I'm also not very up to date, so the names are gave above are only to give you an idea of what I'm talking about. Search for "MIDI guitar" or "MIDI guitar converter", see what products are available, read reviews.

You may also want to get interested in musicians who use guitars with MIDI; Pat Metheny and Allan Holdsworth come to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

You would still need the virtual instrument to make the actual sound.
You guitar could be used as a Midi generator, by one of several methods.

Basically, these are…

1. A full-blown designed from scratch actual dedicated Midi capable guitar.
   e.g the [Jammy](https://playjammy.com)

[image]

2. An add-on pickup that does the Midi conversion for you - stick-on Midi.
   e.g. Fishman Tripleplay [Midi output] or Roland GTK [no midi out, must be used with Roland GTK system]

[image]

3. A software converter plugin that sits in your DAW & transcribes guitar input 'live' to Midi
   e.g [Jam Origin](https://www.jamorigin.com)

[image]

I've never tried any of these. I used to have a Yamaha version of the stick-on system which worked pretty well, but they don't seem to make them any more.